# Do these two sentences have the same meaning? A boy is in green T-shirt and A boy is wearing a T-shirt which is green colour

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

> A boy is wearing a T-shirt which is green colour.

To make it less clumsy, I rewrite it this way:

> A boy is in green T-shirt

Do the two sentences have any difference in meaning now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A boy is wearing *a* green T-shirt.
>
> That's a picture of a boy in *a* green T-shirt.
>
> A boy is wearing a T-shirt, which is green <strike>colour</strike>.
>
> A boy is wearing a T-shirt, which is a greenish colour.

When stating the color by its name ("green"), we don't add the word "colour" afterwards. But when saying that the color is in a particular color *range*, that there is an admixture of another color or colors ("greenish"), then we do add the word "colour" afterwards.  The word "greenish" could suggest an admixture of yellow, like a pea-green, or it could suggest an admixture of blue, like a teal.

The underlying fact is the same when we use **is in** and **is wearing**. They are synonymous expressions.

*She is in a wool coat. She is wearing a wool coat.*

Comment: People sometimes do say "green in color". I've never understood why. As opposed to what? "Green in height"? "Green in religion"? It makes sense in cases where a word can be a color and can also be something else, like "caramel".

Comment: English speakers have been saying *tall in height* and other similar things.

Comment: @tonamor Oh, absolutely true. It's not just color where people do this, it's many things.

Comment: @ Tᴚoɯɐuo can you see me?

Comment: @kitty: I can see your words.

Comment: Good to see you, @Tᴚoɯɐuo . Would you mind if I call you by your username? I had clicked to read your profile but could not find your name. I would like to say thank you to you for your comments and answers in most of my questions.

Comment: @kitty: you are welcome. It is normal practice here to use the username, so that is not a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the meaning is the same for both.
I would modify them a bit, though:

> A boy is wearing a T-shirt which is green **in** colour.
>   A boy is wearing a T-shirt which is green colour**ed**.
>   A boy is wearing a T-shirt which is green.

The third is the best since "green" in this context already means the color green so you don't need to add it specifically.

> A boy is wearing a green T-shirt.

This fourth would be more common though.

---

As for the second sentence, I think it misses an indefinite article:

> A boy is in **a** green T-shirt.

that seems a lot better, although without context **to me** it still sounds a bit off. It's not wrong, it is correct both syntactically and semantically.